# ASP.net Framework and blocked threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

Can anyone explain the following behaviour of an ASP.net webform on IIS. When I have a page and start it 4 times, the pages are served synchroniously. In other words if this page takes about 10 seconds to build, I see the first page appear at around 10sec, 2nd at 20sec, 3rd at 30sec, 4th at 40sec. When asking the threadnumber I usually see 2 threadnumbers, which makes me think IIS/ASP.net is only having two threads in IIS per application pool?

Small example:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.Label1.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        }
```

When I look for suggestions on the internet I find that I should program asynchroniously and for example use await Task.Delay to not block the thread, but I still have the same result when I use this Page_Load:

```
        protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(10000);
            this.Label1.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        }
```

Can anyone explain me this behaviour? First of all if there are two threads I would expect two pages being served at 10sec and the 3rd and 4th at 20sec. But even when I run the code with async it doesn't really make much/any difference. How can I circumvent this blocking of threads with an easy solution?

Best regards,
Rémy Samulski

EDIT: I was calling the website from the same browser and the same URL. This caused the issue. Thx to Richard for helping me figuring out my mistake.

Comment: Do you have session state enabled? If you're making all four requests from the same client, sharing the same session ID, the requests have to be serialized.

Comment: Hi Richard, when I put "EnableSessionState="False"" in the page source I still have same issue. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The next thing to check would be which server you're using - IIS on non-server versions of Windows [limits the number of concurrent connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions) based on the edition used.

Comment: Hi Richard, I tested it on IIS Express (development) and on our IIS server (Windows Server 2016 Standard with IIS 10).

Comment: How are you making the requests? Perhaps the browser is limiting the number of concurrent requests?